# Count of array inside NSDictionary is not logged although the array itself is logged

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary, nslog

I'm, working with an `NSMutableArray` called `sections` to store the section data for my `UITableView` in.

Each section is an `NSDictionary` containing the following items: `Stuff`, another array to hold the data rows of the section, and `Header`, a string for the section's header title.

The problem I am having is trying to get the count of the `Stuff` array.

```
NSLog(@"Returning the count of %@", [[[sections objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Stuff"] count]);
```

I have been able to confirm that `[[sections objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Stuff"]` does in fact get me the array; if I do this

```
NSLog(@"returning the contents of %@", [[sections objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Stuff"]);
```

the contents are logged.

I also know that normally `[Stuff count]` would happily return the count of the array.

Am I missing something here or is it different because the array is in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary doesn't know what kind of objects it hold so you must tell it by either assigning to an NSMutableArray or in your case, casting the object returned from your dictionary to NSMutableArray *

```
NSLog(@"Returning the count of %@", [(NSArray *)[[sections objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Stuff"] count]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy answer. That fixed me right up. For future reference will I need to typecast like that any time I need to access array methods for an array in a dictionary?

Answer (score 4):

You're using `%@` as a format specifier, but `[NSArray count]` returns an `NSUinteger`.

According to the [format specifier docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), you should instead be casting it to an unsigned long and using `%lu`. If you're going iOS only, `%u` without cast should do just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I just typed the %@ in there. In my code I'm actually using %i and it seems to be working fine after implementing Kirby's typecast fix.

Answer (score 0):

The `-count` method returns an integer, not an object, so you need to use the proper format specifier:

```
NSLog(@"Returning the count of %d", [[[sections objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Stuff"] count]);
```

Note the use of `%d` instead of `%@`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Returning the count of %@", [[[sections objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Stuff"] count]);
```

this should work..except one big mistake.. **%@** is for objects(pointers)  .. what you are getting is a integer(array count)  ..change %@ to %d and try again